# Python - Looping (Closest to Average)

Tags: python

I'm a beginner to Python and I'm having some trouble. I want to write a function that returns the element of from a user defined list that is closest to the average of the values of that list.

For example, `closest_to_average([0, 5, -1, 6, 1])` should return `1` because the average value of those elements is `2.2` and the element in that list which is closest to `2.2` is `1`.

By the way, I want to do this using only `len()`, `range()`, loops, `if`-statements, variables and arithmetic (no built in functions).

Here's the code I have so far:

```
def closest_to_average(xs):
    avg = sum(xs)/len(xs)
    for i in xs:
        diffo = 100
        diff = abs(avg - i)
        if diff < diffo:
            return diff
```

So basically, my logic behined this was that, first, the variable average refers to the average of the list. Then each time the loop runs, it will find the difference between i and the average, and if that difference is less than the previous difference, it will keep checking all elements until it finds the i element such that the difference between it and the average is the least.

The problem is I don't know how to set an initial distance! It has to compare the distance between the first i and the average to something. So I set diffo = 100 out of the sake of trying, but I highly doubt that's the solution.

Comment: " I want to do this using only `len()`, `range()`, loops, if-statements, variables and arithmetic " But you're using `abs` and `sum`.

Comment: Oh those are okay, I mean I don't think you can sum all the elements without using "sum", can you..?

Comment: Sure you could. I'm just trying to figure out what you're okay with using.

Comment: Oh well that's another story. From now on, "sum" and "abs" are legal

Comment: What about `max` and `min` (By the way, this is to show you that it's silly to arbitrarily remove parts of the stdlib).

Comment: No I can't use any built ins besides the ones listed.

Comment: Why can't you? What's stopping you?

Comment: You do not need an initial value. Save the first element in a container plus its diff. Loop over the list. If  an element has a diff  smaller than the current one in the container, update the container. After the loop simply return the container.

Comment: You're returning as soon as you find the first element that's closer than `diffo`. You need to keep looping through the entire list, and update `diffo` every time it's smaller.

Comment: @AbSaintDane ...and do not forget to upvote comments and especially solutions which are helpful. Just marking one as "accepted answer" is not very polite to the others ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
def closest_to_average(xs):
    avg = sum(xs)/len(xs)
    min_diff = None
    closest = None
    for i in xs:
        diff = abs(avg - i)
        if min_diff is None or diff < min_diff:
            min_diff = diff
            closest = i
    return closest
```

Comment: You do not need to initialize it with `None`. The algorithm will do fine, if you initialize `min_diff` and `clostest` always with the first value of the list. The algorithm ensures that always the one with the smallest *diff* is returned. This also simplifies `if min_diff is None or diff < min_diff` to `if diff < min_diff`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you could use `min`, it becomes

```
def closest_to_average(lst):
    avg = sum(lst) / len(lst)
    return min(lst, key = lambda x: abs(avg - x))
```

In your example, setting `disto` to *any* arbitrary number is a bad idea, because it could be less than the actual answer. Why not set it to the first item in your list instead? You know that is at least potentially the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
def closest_to_average(xs):
    avg = sum(xs)/len(xs)
    closest = 0
    for i in xs:
        diff = abs(avg - i)
        if diff < abs(avg - closest):
            closest = i
    return closest 

print(closest_to_average([0, 5, -1, 6, 1]))
print(closest_to_average([1, 11474, 1004]))
print(closest_to_average([2, 2, 2, 2, 2]))
print(closest_to_average([2, 1, 0, -9, 9]))
```

I included some cases for this; does this meet your needs?

I rushed this on my phone; sorry if it isn't fully tested.

Comment: Why using `range(len(xs))`? `for i in xs` is more pythonic in this scenario. Additionally `return xs[index]` requires traversing the list. Since the question was returning the value I would suggest storing the value and its *diff*.